# How can I do license key with Magento 2 extension?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to know how can I use the license key for the magento 2 extension, like Its only used on the one domain, If customer can not copy that if they want to use in another site they have to buy the license key or purchase it.

Can you please know how I can do that

Thanks